# Simple accordion using jquery but if i want to close single so i can't

Tags: jquery

Here i had created simple accordion using jquery but when i want to close an open div so it open again so please give me correction on my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".que").addClass('inactive');
$('div.active').click(function(){
    //$(this).css( "background-color", "red" );
    $(this).next("div.ans").slideUp(500);
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
$('div.inactive').click(function(){
    $(".active").next("div.ans" ).slideUp(500);
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
    $( this ).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
    $(this).next("div.ans" ).slideDown(500);
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spghptrt/5/

Comment: What is not working, here?

Comment: if a want to close an open ans than it cant closed.

Answer (score 1):

Do away with the active/inactive classes - just check the answer visibility, and take aciton based on that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.que').click(function(){
        var ans = $(this).next('div.ans');
        if(ans.is(':visible')){
            $(this).next("div.ans").slideUp(500);
        } else {
            $(this).next("div.ans" ).slideDown(500);
        }
    });
});
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/spghptrt/9/)

You could also add a click handler to `div.ans` if you wanted to hide it if they click the answer text...

```
$('div.ans').click(function(){
    $(this).slideUp(500);
});
```

[Here's a fiddle with that added.](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/spghptrt/11/)

Comment: Thanx Mr. @dave-salomon but i want that if any question clicked that's answer is not visible than other visible answer should automatically slideUp and answer of clicked question should slideDown

Comment: Thanx Mr. @dave-salomon i got my answer by updating your suggested answer.

Comment: No problem @PHPLearner. Dont forget to mark one of the answers as accepted ;). Adding `$('div.ans').slideUp(500);` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I got the answer of my problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('div.que').click(function(){
    $('div.ans').slideUp(500);
    var ans = $(this).next('div.ans');
    if(!ans.is(':visible')){
        $(this).next("div.ans" ).slideDown(500);
    }
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spghptrt/18/